# How to extract / update attribute values in Oracle 12g XML by attribute value

Tags: xml, attributes, extract

Hello I'm new to Oracle XML DB but have to extract attribute values by another attribute value.

The simplified document looks like this:

```
<ApplicationDataNotification>
    <ApplicationData>
        <DataSet Name="A1">
            <Data DataElement="PAND" Value="A100"/>
            <Data DataElement="MKDI" Value="007"/>
        </DataSet>
        <DataSet Name="A2">
            <Data DataElement="PAND" Value="B200"/>
            <Data DataElement="MKDI" Value="900"/>
        </DataSet>
    </ApplicationData>
</ApplicationDataNotification>
```

If to use positional notation it works (returns: A100):

```
with testTable(xml_val) 
as (  
    select xmltype(  
    '    
        <ApplicationDataNotification>
            <ApplicationData>
                <DataSet Name="A1">
                    <Data DataElement="PAND" Value="A100"/>
                    <Data DataElement="MKDI" Value="007"/>
                </DataSet>
                <DataSet Name="A2">
                  <Data DataElement="PAND" Value="B200"/>
                  <Data DataElement="MKDI" Value="900"/>
                </DataSet>
            </ApplicationData>
        </ApplicationDataNotification>
    ') from dual)  
select xmlcast(xmlquery('/ApplicationDataNotification/ApplicationData/DataSet[1]/Data[1]/@Value' passing xml_val returning content) as varchar2(2000)) as PAN
    from testTable;
```

But the problem is that the order of xml tags is not fixed.

Thus I tried to use this approach:

```
with testTable(xml_val) 
as (  
    select xmltype(  
    '    
        <ApplicationDataNotification>
            <ApplicationData>
                <DataSet Name="A1">
                  <Data DataElement="PAND" Value="A100"/>
                  <Data DataElement="MKDI" Value="007"/>
                </DataSet>
                <DataSet Name="A2">
                  <Data DataElement="PAND" Value="B200"/>
                  <Data DataElement="MKDI" Value="900"/>
                </DataSet>
            </ApplicationData>
        </ApplicationDataNotification>
        ') from dual)  
select xmlcast(xmlquery('/ApplicationDataNotification/ApplicationData/DataSet[Name="A1"]/Data[DataElement="PAND"]/@Value' passing xml_val returning content) as varchar2(2000)) as PAN
    from testTable;
```

And it returns null.

Sorry but I'm puzzled... Could you give a helpful hand please!
How to re-write the query to make work?
P.S.: Oracle 12g

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the is simple:
The '@' is omitted
select xmlcast(xmlquery('/ApplicationDataNotification/ApplicationData/DataSet[@Name="A1"]/Data[@DataElement="PAND"]/@Value' passing xml_val returning content) as varchar2(2000)) as PAN
    from testTable;

Answer (score 0):

With FLWOR expression could be something like this:

```
with testTable(xml_val) 
as (  
    select xmltype(  
    '    
        <ApplicationDataNotification>
            <ApplicationData>
                <DataSet Name="A1">
                  <Data DataElement="PAND" Value="A100"/>
                  <Data DataElement="MKDI" Value="007"/>
                </DataSet>
                <DataSet Name="A2">
                  <Data DataElement="PAND" Value="B200"/>
                  <Data DataElement="MKDI" Value="900"/>
                </DataSet>
            </ApplicationData>
        </ApplicationDataNotification>
        ') from dual)  
select xmlquery('for $i in /ApplicationDataNotification/ApplicationData/DataSet
                 let $j := $i/Data[@DataElement = "PAND"]
                 where $i/@Name eq "A1" 
                 return $j/@Value'
                 passing xml_val returning content) colval
  from testTable;
```